# How to extract a particular text form a string with condition in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How to extract a particular value form a textbox (string) and put it into another text box using j-query with condition in click event of a button?

I have two text box:

```
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD[HYB]">
<input type="text" id="code-name" value="HYB">
```

Button :

```
<button type="button" id="submit">Search</button>
```

I have use code for button [submit] on click event:

```
$('#code-name').val($('#full-name').val().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]);
```

Up to this it work fine. Now I want to add a condition like, if full-name value contains with [...] then code-name value as above and  full-name value not contains [....] then code-name value will same as full-name.

Like:

```
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD[HYB]">
<input type="text" id="code-name" value="HYB">
                   AND
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD">
<input type="text" id="code-name" value="HYDERABAD">
```

Note that - code-name value will to convert to upper string if user type in lower case in full-name in both case. Sorry for bad english. How to I do this?

Comment: tell me about the expected output ?

Comment: i have update question with expected output@JqueryKing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  var mystring = $('#full-name').val();
  var matches = mystring.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);

  if (matches) {
    $('#code-name').val(matches[1].toUpperCase());
  }else{
$('#code-name').val(mystring.toUpperCase());
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="full-name" value="HYDERABAD[HYB]">
<input type="text" id="code-name" value="HYB">
<button type="button" id="submit">Search</button>
```

Comment: code-name value will to convert to upper string if user type in lower case in full-name.

Comment: @BikashMahata check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript string indexOf function to see if a string contains another string as:

```
var fullname = $('#full-name').val();
var searchFor = 'string-to-search-in-fullname';
if(fullname.indexOf(searchFor) !== -1) {
    // fullname contains searchFor string
} else { 
   // fullname not contain searchFor string
}
```